# Why are some people jealous of other people's success?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology

I have seen many time in my life where I encountered few peoples who hate those person who are going great with their life and achieving something. I mean why some people hate those person who are doing great in some particular field but the other guy is not able to do it.

For example, if 2 persons are working together and among them one of them is getting famous and achieving so many things then the other guy starts hating him and sees him as an enemy or rival.

Is there any explanation behind this type of behaviour or it is common to most of the people as it is natural?

Comment: This is also known as "pecking order". A person with more success/power is perceived as rising on the pecking order, which may make others competitive. Also, I've read that fluctuations in social hierarchy or primates are stressful for all involved.

Comment: Can we fix the title? "Jealousy" means fear of losing what you have. "Envy" means wanting something another person has. They are completely opposite and this misuse of the words is endemic.

Answer (score 4):

Social Order and Hierarchy. As Humans our brains are designed to see where we fit in the social order. If someones success is perceived as a threat, it can lead to anxiety and fear from the person whom is resentful and jealous.

While in the modern world there is no need for this fear, our ancestors had to compete within their tribe(s) for resources,status,choice etc. If one member of the tribe gained more status than another they would have more access to resources, supplies, privilege, reproductive power etc. This could lead to competition from other members of the tribe fearful that they would not have enough resources, or access to enough supplies, ultimately seeing one of their tribe members as a potential threat to their own well-being.This applies to survival and reproduction value as well.

In conclusion: While this type of behavior can still be common, it is a highly outdated form of thinking that comes from our hardwired tribe mentality, defense mechanisms,and the need for humans to look for for a social order and hierarchy in modern society.